# Less Cannot find variable 'xxx'

Tags: css, angular, less, ngx-charts

I am trying to implement a dark theme in `ngx-charts`. I am quite new in using `less`. Below is the code

My IDE is complaining `Cannot find variable 'color-bg-darker'` and compilation fails

```
Error: ./src/styles.less
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js):


     */
  $color-bg-darkest: #13141b;
^
Unrecognised input
      Error in C:\Users\KOTIENO1\Desktop\Projects\GariambaInvoicing\angular-invoicing-frontend\src\styles.less (line 397, column 2)
    at C:\Users\KOTIENO1\Desktop\Projects\GariambaInvoicing\angular-invoicing-frontend\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:316:20
    at C:\Users\KOTIENO1\Desktop\Projects\GariambaInvoicing\angular-invoicing-frontend\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
    at C:\Users\KOTIENO1\Desktop\Projects\GariambaInvoicing\angular-invoicing-frontend\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
    at context.callback (C:\Users\KOTIENO1\Desktop\Projects\GariambaInvoicing\angular-invoicing-frontend\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
    at Object.lessLoader (C:\Users\KOTIENO1\Desktop\Projects\GariambaInvoicing\angular-invoicing-frontend\node_modules\less-loader\dist\index.js:57:5)
```

Below is the extract of my **styles.less** throwing this error

```css
.dark {
  /**
     * Backgrounds
     */
  $color-bg-darkest: #13141b;
  $color-bg-darker: #1b1e27;
  $color-bg-dark: #232837;
  $color-bg-med: #2f3646;
  $color-bg-light: #455066;
  $color-bg-lighter: #5b6882;

  /**
     * Text
     */
  $color-text-dark: #72809b;
  $color-text-med-dark: #919db5;
  $color-text-med: #A0AABE;
  $color-text-med-light: #d9dce1;
  $color-text-light: #f0f1f6;
  $color-text-lighter: #fff;

  background: $color-bg-darker;

  .ngx-charts {

    text {
      fill: $color-text-med;
    }

    .tooltip-anchor {
      fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    }

    .gridline-path {
      stroke: $color-bg-med;
    }

    .refline-path {
      stroke: $color-bg-light;
    }

    .reference-area {
      fill: #fff;
    }

    .grid-panel {
      &.odd {
        rect {
          fill: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
        }
      }
    }

    .force-directed-graph {
      .edge {
        stroke: $color-bg-light;
      }
    }

    .number-card {
      p {
        color: $color-text-light;
      }
    }

    .gauge {
      .background-arc {
        path {
          fill: $color-bg-med;
        }
      }

      .gauge-tick {
        path {
          stroke: $color-text-med;
        }

        text {
          fill: $color-text-med;
        }
      }
    }

    .linear-gauge {
      .background-bar {
        path {
          fill: $color-bg-med;
        }
      }

      .units {
        fill: $color-text-dark;
      }
    }

    .timeline {
      .brush-background {
        fill: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05);
      }

      .brush {
        .selection {
          fill: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
          stroke: #aaa;
        }
      }
    }

    .polar-chart .polar-chart-background {
      fill: rgb(30, 34, 46);
    }

  }

  .chart-legend {
    .legend-labels {
      background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05) !important;
    }

    .legend-item {
      &:hover {
        color: #fff;
      }
    }

    .legend-label {
      &:hover {
        color: #fff !important;
      }

      .active {
        .legend-label-text {
          color: #fff !important;
        }
      }
    }

    .scale-legend-label {
      color: $color-text-med;
    }
  }

  .advanced-pie-legend {
    color: $color-text-med;

    .legend-item {
      &:hover {
        color: #fff !important;
      }
    }
  }

  .number-card .number-card-label {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    color: $color-text-med;
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe [variables in LESS start with `@` not `$`](http://lesscss.org/#variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `$` sign into `@` like in [docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/coding-standards/code-standard-less.html#naming).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had missed that